# Problema al recuperar variable .env en Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

estoy intentando recuperar en un controlador un valor desde MI_VARIABLE en .env. Para ello uso `env('MI_VARIABLE', 'default');` pero no funciona, siempre me trae 'default'. Ya limpié el cache, reinicié apache, pero no hay caso. Estoy usando Laravel 6.

Comment: ¿probaste con `getenv('var');`?

Comment: Detuviste la aplicación Laravel? Usualmente debes reiniciar para ver los cambios del .env

Comment: Finalmente resolví creando variables en un archivo de config y desde ese archivo usaba el helper env(...), luego desde el controlador llamaba el helper config(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que después de cambiar cualquier configuración en tu archivo .env debes ejecutar el comando `php artisan config:cache`, para que funcione correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Alcanza con usar el helper [env](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-env) el cual te va a servir para recuperar el valor de una variable de ambiente que tiene asignado el valor para la configuración donde tu software esta ejecutándose.

En tu controlador escribe lo siguiente:

```
$data = env('DB_USERNAME');
```

Ahora retornalo

```
return $data;
```

Lo cual te debe devolver algo como esto:

> root